# Delphi XE2 Graph slow

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

I'm making a Delphi application with which I want to display data in a graph. This data comes through the serial port so I want to see 'real time' what happens. I noticed that my application becomes very slow after some time. I think it has to do with updating the graph. Can somebody help me with making my application faster? For testing purposes I made this test application where I get a random number every 5 ms and add it to the graph, so this is not my final application but the effect is the same. If I try to measure the time with GetTickCount I see that the time 'In Between' goes up. In my final application i need to be able to place 12 graphs. Is there a way to make it faster?

Thank you!

[Source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12289135/Chart%20Example.zip)

unit MainUnit;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, VCLTee.TeEngine,
  VCLTee.Series, VCLTee.TeeProcs, VCLTee.Chart, DateUtils, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ComCtrls, Math;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Chart01: TChart;
    AreaSeries4: TAreaSeries;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    AddLabel: TLabel;
    InBetweenLabel: TLabel;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    AfterAddPoint: integer;
    procedure FillChart(RealValue: real);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation


procedure TMainForm.FillChart(RealValue: real);
var Chart: TChart;
begin
  Chart:=MainForm.Chart01;

  Chart.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(IncMinute(Now, -20), Now);  //Moet hier staan, anders worden grafieken niet live geupdate

  Chart.Series[0].AddXY(Now, RealValue, '' );

end;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var BeforeAddPoint, Diverence: integer;
begin
  BeforeAddPoint:= GetTickCount;
  Diverence:=BeforeAddPoint-AfterAddPoint;
  InBetweenLabel.Caption:=IntToStr(Diverence);

  FillChart(RandomRange(50,52));

  AfterAddPoint:=GetTickCount;
  Diverence:=AfterAddPoint-BeforeAddPoint;
  AddLabel.Caption:=IntToStr(Diverence);

end;

end.
```

Comment: We don't know very much. We don't know what type of series you are using. Certainly TChart can display large volumes of data efficiently.

Comment: Yes, I use TChart. And the AreaSeries. I wanted to make a chart that scrols the old data to the left and on the right side new data is added. Does this help? I added a link with the project.

Comment: The information that you use an area series is quite important. If I were you I'd make an MCVE so that we can investigate.

Comment: I think thats what i did. I made a simple example with which i CAN reproduse the problem. You can download it. See link 'source'. Or isn't that what you mean?

Comment: It needs to be in the question. Off site links are not good.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding TeeChart use and optimization in your application, I strongly recommend you to follow what's explained in the *Real-time charting* article at http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php